# What interest rate is needed to increase \$24 to \$1 trillion in 388 years?

Tags: calculus

In 1626, Peter Minuit traded trinkets worth \$24 for land on Manhattan Island. Assume that in 2014 the same land was worth \$1 trillion. Find the annual rate of interest compounded continuously at which the \$24 would have had to be invested during this time to yield the same amount.

Comment: Tell us what you've done. What do you know about continuous compounding? Surely you've at least tried to set the problem up.

Comment: Would "more than the interest my bank is giving me now" be a sufficient answer? :-)

Comment: I changed the title because the previous title, "word problem" led me to believe this was a problem on group theory.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for continuous compound interest is given by 
$$
A(t)=Pe^{rt}
$$
Where $P$ is the principal quantity invested, $r$ is the rate, $t$ is the amount of time the interest has been accruing, and $A(t)$ is the amount in the bank at time $t$. This comes from the limiting value of 
$$
(1+r/n)^{rn}
$$
in terms of $n$, the number of times interest is compounded. As mentioned in the comments, using this formula is justified as given the length of the time span, you are compounding "a lot."

So solving
$$
10^{12}=24e^{388r}
$$
For $r$. So
$$
\ln 10^{12}=\ln 24 +388r\Rightarrow r=\frac{1}{388}\ln\frac{10^{12}}{24}
$$
or roughly .06.

Comment: You might check your calculation.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(10%5E12%2F24)%2F388) gives $r \approx 0.063$

Comment: @RossMillikan oops yeah forgot the coefficient on the log

Comment: A nit:  the formula you used is for continuous compounding, while the question seems to ask for annual compounding.  The difference is pretty small.

Comment: @RossMillikan ah ok, so replacing $r/388$ should do the trick yes?

Comment: No, I would write $10^{12}=24(1+r')^388 $, which gives $\log (1+r')$ for the same value you got for $r$. For $r \ll 1$ they are very close.  It raises the stated rate per year to about $0.065$

Comment: ohhhh I see I am sorry. I will add a note. I appreciate the clarification